# How to configure Master-Slave LDAP replication

Tags: ldap, openldap

How  do I configure Master-Slave LDAP server on Ubuntu with session replication.

For example If and ldap client changes his password on the master server. I want the new password to be synchronized automatically to the slave server

Answer (score 5):

Master slave in ldap goes by the name of provider and consumer. You don't specify what ldap server you are using so I presume we are talking about openLDAP.

In older openLDAP config was saved in conf files. Nowadays all settings are stored in the ldap server itself. So you need to create the config and inject it to the ldap server so we will start by creating these files. This instruction will replicate all entries to your slave server automatically.

Lets say your company name is acme and the domain is com.
and that your current ldap server admin is located in : cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com

**First** we need to create a ldap user that is allowed to read all ldap entries to replicated it to the consumer server.

create file "create_repl_user.ldif"

```
dn: cn=ldaps2,dc=acme,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: ldaps2
description: LDAP server2 replicator
```

**Second** we need to enable the provider service in the master ldap server and give the user ldaps2 read access to the entire ldap server.

create file "enable_sync_prov.ldif"

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com write
  by * none
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com" write
  by dn="cn=ldaps2,dc=acme,dc=com" read
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq

dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: {1}syncprov

dn: olcOverlay=syncprov,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: {0}syncprov
olcSpCheckpoint: 100 10
olcSpSessionlog: 100
```

**Third**: We need to enable replicating from a specified server to our ldap consumer.
create the file enable_sync_consumer.ldif replacing the line
provider="ldap://yourldapservername.com:389/" , with the ip of your master ldap server.
and
credentials=yourencryptedldap2spassword , with the password you decide on for your ldap2s user.

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: stats

dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com" write
  by * none
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
  by anonymous auth
  by * none
-
delete: olcAccess
olcAccess: {2}to *
  by self write
  by dn="cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com" write
  by * read
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {2}to *
  by * read
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=manager
-
delete: olcRootPW
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryCSN eq
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: entryUUID eq
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: uid eq
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: cn eq
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: ou eq
-
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: dc eq


add: olcSyncrepl
olcSyncrepl: rid=123
  provider="ldap://yourldapservername.com:389/"
  type=refreshAndPersist
  retry="60 30 300 +"
  searchbase="dc=acme,dc=com"
  bindmethod=simple
  binddn="cn=ldaps2,dc=acme,dc=com"
  credentials=yourencryptedldap2spassword
```

Now that we have created the config files, we need to inject them to the provider and consumer server

in the provider server 
create the replication user:

```
run ldapadd -x -W -D cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com -f  create_repl_user.ldif
```

enable the provider service:

```
run ldapadd -x -W -D cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com -f  enable_sync_prov.ldif
```

in the consumer server add the consumer sync settings:

```
run ldapadd -x -W -D cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com -f enable_sync_consumer.ldif
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. Note that the database is not necessarily "hdb", so this must be adapted. I use mdb, so I had to change all `dn:` which mention `olcDatabase={1}hdb` to `olcDatabase={1}mdb`.

Answer (score 2):

great article, helped me forward a lot, there are a few errors in the ldifs though , to watch out for: enable_sync_prov.ldif

> by dn="cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=ncom write

should be

> by dn="cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com" write

Then the ldapadd/ldapmodify should be ran on cn=admin,cn=config portion of the tree , and not on cn=admin,dc=acme,dc=com.